# How to update height prop with useRef in React?

Tags: reactjs

I need to dynamically define the size of HTML element and set its height to component. I tried to do this with useRef but it doesn't work as expected because of state which contains the previous value (not the current one). Could someone help me with this?

And here's the link:  CodeSandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-water-fzqk8?file=/src/App.js

The below code works fine but there's hardcored variable HEIGHT which defines the height of a tab. My task is to make the height dynamic

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const HEIGHT = {
  0: 200,
  1: 400,
  2: 800,
}

function App() {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);

  const switchTab = (id) => {
    setTab(id);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        margin: '100px auto',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        width: '400px',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: HEIGHT[tab], // need this to be dynamic not hardcored
      }}
    >
      <div>
        {tab === 0 && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <h2>Tab 1</h2>
            <input />
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(1)}>Go to tab 2</button>
            <p>Some text here</p>
          </div>
        )}
        {tab === 1 && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <h2>Tab 2</h2>
            <input />
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(0)}>Go to tab 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(2)}>Go to tab 3</button>
            <p>
              Some more text here. Some more text here. Some more text here. Some more text here.
              Some more text here. Some more text here. Some more text here
            </p>
          </div>
        )}

        {tab === 2 && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <h2>Tab 3</h2>
            <input />
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(0)}>Go to tab 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(1)}>Go to tab 2</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I tried:

1. Added useRef and state which holds the element height

```
    const elRef = useRef(0);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(elRef.current.offsetHeight);
```

2. Added function which calculates the size of an element and then sets it to state variable

```
      const resizeHeight = useCallback(() => {
        const size = elRef.current.offsetHeight;
        setHeight(size)
      }, [elRef]);
```

3. Added state Height to styles this way

```
    <div
      style={{
        margin: '100px auto',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        width: '400px',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: height, // it should be the element size
      }}
    >
```

It doesn't work((
Here's the link...with the state height - undefined
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-brown-zq7ih?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily update your `elRef` reference in the `switchTab` handler without using `useEffect` and any `useCallback` hooks:

```
const elRef = useRef(0);

const SwitchTab = (id) => {
  setTab(id);
  setHeight(elRef.current.offsetHeight)
};
```

Now pass the `elRef` to the `ref` property of your **target** `div`:

```
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        margin: '100px auto',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        width: '400px',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: HEIGHT[tab],
      }}
    >
      <div ref={elRef}>    // ------------------------> added here
        {tab === 0 && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <h2>Tab 1</h2>
            <input />
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(1)}>Go to tab 2</button>
            <p>Some text here</p>
          </div>
        )}
        {tab === 1 && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <h2>Tab 2</h2>
            <input />
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(0)}>Go to tab 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(2)}>Go to tab 3</button>
            <p>
              Some more text here. Some more text here. Some more text here. Some more text here.
              Some more text here. Some more text here. Some more text here
            </p>
          </div>
        )}

        {tab === 2 && (
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <h2>Tab 3</h2>
            <input />
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(0)}>Go to tab 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => switchTab(1)}>Go to tab 2</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Might be because my post was not clear. I updated it, can you take a look please? I was told that we need to specify element height because of animation/transition (without height animation is not working). So my task is to remove hardcoded HEIGHT and replace it with useRef somehow

Comment: You didn't pass the "elRef" to the "div" element, you may forget it. I checked your updates and code sandboxes, all things work fine with the above implementation I explained to you. so pass the "formRef" or in the new version "elRef" to a ref property of a "div" element which you want to know it's the height @qweezz

Comment: At the moment if I add <div ref={elRef}> as you ponited out then the unexpected behavior happens. I mean if you click on different tabs (buttons) then you will see all content as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-brown-zq7ih?file=/src/App.js .But if add <div ref={elRef}> and click button Tab2 then you will the not full content of that element... I mean try to click Tab2 with and without ref ...you will see the different result...but I need the same...I added a pic in post...please take a look